# Remove Numbers in Notepad++ but do not change in Brackets

Tags: notepad++

I have text

```
 1.Word
 2.Word
"3.Word"
```

Want to change all numbers in 1 word 2 word but don't change numbers between brackets "3.Word"

i'm using notepad++

Comment: Change the numbers to _what_ ?

Comment: What is the expected result? I don't see any brackets, do you mean double quotes `"`?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+F - Replace - Search mode: regular expression

Find What: ^\h*\d+[image]

Replace With:

// Replace with is empty

Comment: will also replace quoted word

Comment: try this ^\h*\d+

Answer (score 0):

Use follwing regex to replace digits that are not in a quoted word

```
(?<!")\d+
```

Comment: This is wrong, because it would match numbers _anywhere_ which are not preceded by a double quote, not just the content highlighted by the OP.

Comment: Correct, it needs first character to be a digit . Seems this is the case with the question also .

Comment: In the line `1.Word 123 and 456`, your replacement would replace _all_ the numbers.

Comment: This will replace `"12.Word"` with `"1.Word"`

Answer (score -1):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    (?<!")\d+(\.\w+)(?!["\w])
Replace: $1
```

### Demo

The pattern works by checking that what precedes the digit is not a double quote, and also that the end of the term is not bounded by another double quote.  It captures everything besides the digit, and then just replaces with the capture group.

Comment: will replace whole word, he is asking just for number

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui How do you know what the OP is asking for?  This isn't entirely clear to me.  And if you bothered to actually check the demo you would see that in fact my regex is only removing the _number_, _not_ the entire word.

Comment: I have checked that its removing 1.word and 2.word fully .

Comment: here is what he says, "Want to change all numbers in 1 word 2 word.... "